# what does calibrate_delay function on system boot

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, timing

From this http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/essentiallinuxdevicedrivers/final/ch02lev1sec1.html

It says

> During boot, the kernel calculates the number of times the processor
>   can execute an internal delay loop in one jiffy, which is the time
>   interval between two consecutive ticks of the system timer.

From Understanding Linux Kernel book it says

> kernel executes the calibrate_delay() function, which determines how
>   many “loops” fit in a tick

I am confused between jiffie and loops_per_jiffie. We already can know the resolution from CONFIG_HZ. For example if CONFIG_HZ is 250, it means one jiffie increment will cost 1/250 = 4 ms

Can anyone explain more about this calibrate_delay() what it is actually calculating ?

Comment: `will cost 1/250 = 4 ms` - yes, but how many instructions will CPU execute in those 4ms? 1000 instructions? 100000 instruction? You have to know, to implement  measurement in like `ndelay` functions.

Comment: So, loops_per_jiffie is number of instructions per jiffie?

Comment: I think that it is in milions of instructions per jiffie.

Comment: So, say i want 1 micro second delay, how i can use this loops_per_jiffie value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `calibrate_delay()` functions in a crude way measures how many instructions can a cpu execute per second. The function is explained in the [wiki about BogoMIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips) also, and the result of this function is the number of famous BogoMIPS. The source of the function is [in init/calibrate.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/init/calibrate.c#L275).

Looking at `pr_cont(...)` call in the source I guess that:

```
1 loops_per_jiffy / (500000/HZ) = 1 BigoMOPS
```

So that means that:

```
1 loops_per_jiffy = 500000 / HZ BigoMOPS
```

So `loops_per_jiffy` looks like the number of 500000 millions of instructions in one jiffy.

> say i want 1 micro second delay, how i can use this loops_per_jiffie value

Read the source. It's implemented for various architectures ex. [udelay() in x86/lib/delay.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/arch/x86/lib/delay.c#L165) function or [udelay() for mips](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/arch/mips/lib/delay.c#L51). It looks it waits for `number_of_useconds_to_wait * loops_per_jiffy / 1000000 * 4 * HZ [+ 1]` loops (or something like that).